# Solving $e^x - 3 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I want to solve this equation for $x$:

$$e^x - 3 = 0$$

Can somebody give me some hints?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you know? what have you tried? how far along are you in mathematics?

Comment: I don't know much... This is high school math

Comment: We can help if you show some effort....How about bringing the $-3$ over to the right?

Comment: Ok than it will be e^x=3

Comment: You must have learned somewhere that $e^x$ and $lnx$ are inverses.That is where the $x=ln3$ comes from as shown below.

Comment: Have you learned any operations that would turn the x from an exponent to something more like .. an  x?  Have you ever seen this $e^x$ character before?  In what context?  Why did he come up?

Comment: Yes I have seen e^x before. I want to solve this because I have this function over here f(x)=e^x/e^x-3

Comment: So what is the differential for this function?

Comment: @Skoutas:  It's not clear how "the differential for this function" relates to your Question here.  Comments should be used to clarify the Question, and not to ask new questions.

Answer (score 3):

$x=\ln(3)$.

Filling up the $30$ characters.

Comment: You should add some explanation. Simply telling someone the answer is rarely helpful to them

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you don't know logarithms and you would like more precise explanation. First, bring the $-3$ to the other side: $$e^x=3$$
Now, to solve equations like this you need logarithms. Let's take a look at this: $2^3=8$ . Two raised to the third power is eight. Keep in mind, $2$ is the **base**. This equation is equal to $\log_28=3$. Notice that the base of the logarithm is $2$ as in $2^3=8$.

So, **logarithms** basically solve "to what power I have to raise a number, to get another number." In the equation $\log_28$ we can ask ourselves what number do I have to raise the **base** $(2)$ to get number $8$. It is $3$, because $2^3=8$.

The same stuff applies when the base is $e$. The equation $e^x=3$ is the same equation as $x=\log_e3$. So to what power do I have to raise $e$ to get $3$. $x=\log_e3$ is the same as $x=\ln3$, where $\ln$ means natural logarithm., or just logarithm with base $e$.

Now, normally you can leave your answer as $x=\ln3$, but if you want to get exact number that is eqal $x$, you just have to compute lnatural logarithm of $3$, which is irrational and it is approximately $1.0986122...$

So, $x=\ln3=1.0986122...$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, add 3 to both sides, making $e^x = 3$.
Next, use this link to solve $e^x = 3$:
http://www.mathpapa.com/algebra-calculator.html

If you want an explanation, here you go:

$$e^x-3=0$$

Add $3$ to both sides:

$$e^x=3$$

Take the **natural** log of both sides:

$$\log(e^x) = \log(3)$$

The left side simplifies to:

$$x = \log(3)$$

Find the answer to that using a calculator.

Comment: Not a good site. It uses a 6-digit approximation to $e$.

Comment: He never asked for that much accuracy.

Comment: It is always safer to use $ln$ instead of $log$ because some people confuse $log$'s without base as logarithms of base $10$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll remember it next time.